# Can I attach to a JVM in a different process?

Tags: java, c++, c, windows, java-native-interface

I have process A and process B.
Process A is not allowed to instantiate its own JVM.
Process B has a running JVM instance.

How can process A attach to the JVM running in process B and use it to run Java code within process A.

Note: Doing the Java processing in process B is not allowed.

Comment: Is there any reason you NEED direct access to  the JVM in process A? Can  just use some file based protocol to communicate  between these processes?

Comment: Socket based protocols are also very good for interprocess communication. Maybe look at something like this: http://zeromq.org

Comment: Can you edit `B` at all? Does `B` already run any kind of remoting service you could use to run code? If not you'll probably have to look into the debugging interfaces to attach to the remote JVM (this doesn't necessarily require Java if you code the "debugger" yourself) and inject code. Sounds like a nasty project...

Answer (score 3):

It is *possible*: this is exactly what a typical Java debugger does. The JVM exports debugging interfaces which you can attach to and use to control the running Java program (including injecting your own code).

You have two options: write a  [Java Debug Wire Protocol (JDWP)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jpda/jdwp-spec.html) client, or write a [JVM Tooling Interface (JVMTI)](http://blog.takipi.com/how-to-write-your-own-java-scala-debugger/) client. The latter is easier, but not as well supported - you'll have to check if your target JVM supports it.

With JVMTI, for example, you would write "debugger" code that is automatically injected into the remote process' JVM using the JVMTI API (which itself is implemented in C/C++, so you don't need a JVM in your process to run it). Your "debugger" code can then do whatever computation it needs.